# Unknown random memory crash in react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, react-redux, react-native-webview

My app is crashing randomly. I tried but unable to debug the exact reason. Below is my crash log:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

Cannot figure out the cause

*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

Build fingerprint: 
'google/sdk_gphone64_arm64/emulator64_arm64:12/SPB5.210812.003/7673742:userdebug/dev- 
keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
Timestamp: 2021-10-22 21:47:08.316997883+0530
Process uptime: 0s
Cmdline: com.travokarma
pid: 10324, tid: 13558, name: mqt_js  >>> com.myapp <<<
uid: 10146
tagged_addr_ctrl: 0000000000000001
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xa
 Cause: null pointer dereference
x0  0000000000000000  x1  00000074b9a62b00  x2  0000000000000000  x3  
0000000000000001
x4  00000074cbaed0a8  x5  0000000000000000  x6  00000000ffffffff  x7  
9100007f35ffffa1
x8  0000007476d60c40  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000000000000000  x11 
0000000000000074
x12 0000007499b681c0  x13 0000007478f00000  x14 00000000e6f51ba1  x15 
 0000000000000001
 x16 00000074ba0b43d8  x17 00000077e92033cc  x18 000000748d020000  x19 
 00000074ba0bd680
 x20 00000074949832a0  x21 0000007499b67c9c  x22 0000007499b67ca0  x23 
 00000074a6a97360
x24 0000007470f75320  x25 0000000000000000  x26 0000000014000000  x27 
00000074cbaf2000
x28 0000007499b67ae0  x29 000000000000008c
lr  00000074b9af40e4  sp  00000074cbaed100  pc  00000074b9af4134  pst 
 0000000060001000
  backtrace:
  #00 pc 00000000002cd134  /data/app/~~hQ28yJARYHhbRdFHaSNmgA==/com.myapp- 
  BqQoaRBCMRHkVLdv7S75eA==/lib/arm64/libjsc.so (BuildId: 
  dad225e5c5aafb43e3fcbfcd576772a6a0f8c19a)
  #01 pc 0000000000296ad4  /data/app/~~hQ28yJARYHhbRdFHaSNmgA==/com.myapp- 
  BqQoaRBCMRHkVLdv7S75eA==/lib/arm64/libjsc.so (BuildId: 
  dad225e5c5aafb43e3fcbfcd576772a6a0f8c19a)
  #02 pc 00000000000032e0  <anonymous:74998ff000>
```

I am using MacBook pro M1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's caused by `libjsc.so`. Update JSC - https://github.com/react-native-community/jsc-android-buildscripts#for-react-native-version-060-and-newer